# How do I search the Wayback Machine for URLs on a website that contain a specific string?

Tags: search, archive.org

I am looking for a way to search on archive.org for URLs of a website, that contain a certain word.

(all my explanations here use 'example.com', but it's not the actual website I am searching for)

When I search for the website in the 'URLs', I find over 10000 entries for the site.
I then use the integrated filter to look for the word 'Baum'. That results in about 90 entries.
But if I search for the URL 'example.com/baum', I find over 800 entries, with 0 overlap to the previous 90 hits.
The 2nd way misses entries like 'example.com/2baum'.
A search for 'example.com*baum' results in an empty result.

The [help website](https://help.archive.org/help/using-the-wayback-machine/) mentions fuzzy URL matching, without going into details about it.

Comment: Hello, I don't get why do people forget to ask a question so often. Questions end with a `?` character. Anyways, even if you did, it could still likely be quite unclear as to what you goal here is. E.g. how is fuzzy matching related to anything that you described?

Comment: @Destroy666 not every request can be formulated as a question..
I segregated my question/request in 3 parts..
1. what i am looking for (in one sentence).
2. what i tried myself, not getting the intended result.
3. what i found in their help to the search (no clue if it actually helps).

Comment: Anything can be formulated with `?` question and that shouldn't be hard under most circumstances. Here you can ask "How can I find `xyz` phrase on a given website?" (which is your first paragraph) or "How can I find `xyz` or similar phrases on a given website?" (which is more of 3rd paragraph). I have no idea what you have exactly on mind so I cna't formulate it for you, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: ok.. to keep with my example: 
I am looking for a way to search all URLs of 'example.com', that contain the word 'baum'. 
Due to the size of the site the integrated filter does not bring the intended result (it only filters the 10000 entries, that you initially got). 
similar issue, wen using 'example.com/baum' I got more results, but that misses any entry, that does not start with 'baum' in the web-path. (note: 'example.com' and 'baum' are placeholders for the actual domain and word i am actually looking for)